# Images inside flexbox not resizing correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, cross-browser

I'm trying to use flexboxes to make an interactive scrolling gallery.

https://www.nickiwells.com/image-issue/#pictures

The layout looks as intended in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the images are not shrinking to the size of the container and are being displayed at the full image size.

The issue seems to be with the height of the containing `.picturesSection.activeSection` div.

If anyone can explain this behaviour that would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `width` and `object-fit` on img tag like

```
img{
  width: 300px;//your desire width % also
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried your suggestion. I set the img width to 100%. This helped with the sizing. But I would like for the vertical space in the `ul `to be filled. So I set added the property `width: max-content;` to the containing `ul`.
BUT now when I check in Chrome the width of the li elements is set to the width of the original image size meaning loads of space either side of each image. Do you have any idea what to try next?

Comment: @BenJackson can you provide us a updated code in snippet or fiddle

Comment: Or you can play with `object-fit` property as 'cover', 'fill' , `no-scale` etc which suits you best